# Можно ли изменить патерн (форматирование) разрыва строки в intellIj idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Мы используем CheckStyle на нашем проекте и та стратегия проверки качества кода что в него заложена не сходится со стратегией форматирования кода intellIj idea. А конкретно речь идет про разрыв строки

```
log.info("first line" +
         "second line");
```

Чек стайл требует чтобы '+' тоже был перенесен на новую строку:

```
log.info("first line"
         + "second line");
```

Однако делать это каждый раз в ручную радости не доставляет.
Можно ли решить эту проблемы со стороны intellIj idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это настраивается в `Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Binary Expressions -> Operation sign on next line`

[image: настройки переноса знака операций в IntelliJ IDEA]